Strange Behaviour with Color Index
I have a workbook for building and publishing work rotas, and use a red colour fill to indicate when a staff member is a shift lead.
I only ever set this format via Range().Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Range().Interior.TintAndShade = 0.8 and this formatting is carried through to 2 other worksheets using Sheets(output).Range(output).Interior.ColorIndex = Sheets(input).Range(input).Interior.ColorIndex (and the same for tint and shade). It carries over to the other worksheets as expected.
However, when I try to transfer this formatting to another cell (with no colour fill) in the final worksheet using the same method, it outputs a yellow colour fill. I've used MsgBox(Range().Interior.ColorIndex) to find that for whatever reason, what looks like a red cell has an index of 19, and what looks like a cell with no colour fill has an index of -4192.
I'm working on finding a way around this issue on my own, but I'm wondering if anybody has an idea of what could be causing it?

Record a macro while setting the fill color of a cell using the drop-down on the home tab, choosing one of the theme colors. You should see colorindex isn't in the code. ColorIndex is there only for backward compatibility.

.ColorIndex=3 only means red if you are using the standard palette. Is your final worksheet in a different workbook, possibly with a different palette preset? If you want to be certain that red actually means red, use .Color=RGB(255,0,0)

NEVER use ColorIndex.  It's the most unreliable way to set a Color there is, since it can change if the user changes their Theme.

Thank you everyone  for your input. I'm changing the formatting to use RGB instead. I'm yet to see if it solves the issue because I've encountered another problem in the process. Will add an answer once I know it's solved.

ColorIndex is only an approximate assessment of color. Regardless of the fact that the scale of indexcolor numbers can be changed by the user (which, however, happens quite rarely), there are only 56 index numbers and over 16 million colors. Therefore, by reading the index number of a color that was somehow modified, and then giving this color (by index) to another cell, we can get a completely different color.
Besides, you also have to be careful when using the TintAndShade property. Always specify Color (or ColorIndex) first, followed by TintAndShade. Setting a cell Color property automatically resets TintAndShade, while changing the TintAndShade to a value <> 0 recalculates the Color value. Therefore, when we use TintAndShade, we will read a Color value different from what we originally assigned. TintAndShade can be modified multiple times until we change the Color.
Unfortunately, there is no way to read the original Color value directly (you can only store TintAndShade, change it to 0, read Color, then restore the TintAndShade value).
Sample codes for testing:
Sub ColorTint()
    With Range("A1").Interior
        .ColorIndex = 3
        Debug.Print "Before: " & .Color  ' 255
        .TintAndShade = 0.8
        Debug.Print "After:  " & .Color  ' 13421823
        Debug.Print "Index:  " & .ColorIndex  ' 3
    End With
End Sub
Sub CopyCell()
    Range("A1").Copy Range("C1")
    Debug.Print "Before: " & Range("C1").Interior.TintAndShade
    Range("C1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Debug.Print "After:  " & Range("C1").Interior.TintAndShade
End Sub
Sub CopyColor()
    Range("D1").Interior.Color = Range("A1").Interior.Color
    Debug.Print "Before: " & Range("D1").Interior.TintAndShade
    Debug.Print "Before: " & Range("D1").Interior.ColorIndex  ' 19
    Range("E1").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End Sub
Sub TestTint()
    Dim temp As Double
    With Range("A7").Interior
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0.8
        Debug.Print .Color
        temp = .TintAndShade
        .TintAndShade = 0
        Debug.Print .Color
        .TintAndShade = temp
    End With
End Sub

